# Inverse of Matrix with normally distributed Elements?

Tags: normal-distribution, matrix-inverse, random-matrix

Let's say we have some Matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n_x \times n_x}$ whose elemets $x_{i,j} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ are normally distributed. In other words: $vec(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(m, S)$, where $m \in \mathbb{R}^{n_x^2}$ and only diagonally set $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n_x^2 \times n_x^2}$. Are we able to calculate its Inverse $X^{-1}$ and/or can we say something about the distribution of its elements?

Let's start with the 2-dimensional case, where 
$X = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ and $X^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$. 
$ad$ and $bc$ are products of Gaussians, which is another Gaussian, right? The subtraction should lead to antoher Gaussian. Thereafter we need its inverse and we are done.

Is there another approach? How can we handle higher dimensions $n_x>2$?

Comment: $X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ then $XY \sim W$, where $W$ is not gaussian (much fatter tails)

Comment: The division by $ad-bc$ also induces correlations among the entries of the inverse.  Notice that in one dimension the inverse doesn't even have an expectation, strongly indicating no higher-dimensional example will have Gaussian entries.

Comment: Here is a relevant paper:  https://www.ugr.es/~ramongs/articulos%20en%20pdf/cimat1.pdf

Comment: life is difficult if we focus on matrix entries. We can instead recognize that the left and right eigenvectors are uniformly distributed on the appropriate space, and that the eigenvalues have a certain distribution: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355947/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-gaussian-random-matrices. Then, the inverse of the matrix has the same eigenvectors but inverted eigenvalues. Are you directly interested in the entries of the matrix, or on some function of them?

Comment: @JohnMadden I am interested in the entries of the inverse. I don't necessarily need the exact probability distributions for these entries, any form of approximation (e.g. normal) would be helpful as well. A analytical closed form would be nice of course, but if there's a efficient numerical solution, I take it.